# cmd msg command won't send to other computers

Tags: windows-7, windows, networking

We've 5 Windows 7 and XP computers connected to a router. And they're in the same workgroup. (I can share file)

I want to send a message to others with Command Prompt. So, as I did before, enter:

`msg * "good morning"`

but it prompts in my computer only. (I'm using Windows 7)

I have searched a lot, and read some solutions (for example check registry and set this key to `1`: `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Terminal Server`), but still can't send message to others.

Do you know how to solve it?

Or can you suggest another command to send simple message to others? (which works in WinXP and Win7)

Answer (score 1):

Try [winsent](http://www.winsentmessenger.com/netsend/).

MS messenging died with Vista SP2. `net send` computers communicate with each other and `MSG` generation ones with each other but getting them to reliably even see each other isn't worth the hassle.

Comment: Can you give a little more info on how to use the program you're recommending?

Comment: Old post, but Winsent works really nice. I'm using it with taskscheduler "on startup" events to announce to my local pc that my servers are ready to be connected to.

Answer (score 0):

The Messenger service must be enabled on all remote computers.  I believe since XP SP2 or similar this was disabled by default because of spam.

Long term if you really need something like this it may be better to install on all systems an IM-like application, though I don't know of any I've really tried off hand.  Pidgin lets you communicate with other clients via the Bonjour protocol and using that may negate the need to have a central server coordinating messages.

Comment: `msg` does not use Messenger, but the Terminal Services RPC.